# Setting up PostGIS on Ubuntu Server 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, postgis

Ubuntu Server 9.04 comes with PostgreSQL 8.3 installed. This is working correctly; I am able to log in, list the databases, etc.

I have tried to follow the instructions [here](http://www.paolocorti.net/2008/01/30/installing-postgis-on-ubuntu/) for installing PostGIS, including a *sudo apt-get install postgis*. This appeared to install version 1.3 of PostGIS okay, but then doing a *locate lwpostgis.sql* or *locate postgis* didn't return any results. Since I was unable to locate these **.sql** files, I was unable to continue with the installation guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `postgresql-8.3-postgis`.

The 1.3 release is quite old: You might want to install potgis 1.4 or even better 1.5 from source, but then you have to compile proj and geos first.

Comment: You're right; my problem was that I originally did **sudo apt-get install postgis** which I thought would work by automatically resolving the version I needed. In fact, it did install _something_ but it appears it was just documentation. Passing **postgresql-8.3-postgis** did it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the output of `dpkg -L postgis`, this should give you a list of all files contained in the package that you installed.

The `locate` command gets its information from a database, which is updated nightly (or manually by running `sudo updatedb`.

Comment: I ran *updatedb* and it now finds PostGIS files. The problem is that it does not find any of the *.sql* files mentioned in the installation guide.

Comment: The output of **dpkg -L postgis** returns a similar list as **locate** but none of the returned files are those **.sql** ones. Basically I just I have some docs in */usr/share/doc/postgis*